# sFIR fonts in an Adobe Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, sifr

Is it possible to use sFIR fonts in an Adobe Flex Web Application (I mean I want to use the sFIR font to apply it to some text on spark controls)? If yes, would somebody be so kind and point out an example.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can just embed the fonts into a flex application.  See http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/10/15/embedding-fonts-in-flex-gumbo/